# Unable to get a Value from Text box using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am unable to get the values present in a text box using selenium getText method.It always return null value.

Also Tried using `js.executeScript("document.getElementById('WBJDCD').value". It also returns null value.

My Html looks as below.

```
<input id="WBJDCD" class="inforTextbox upperCaseClass" type="text" tabindex="-1" readonly="readonly" style="width: 42px; text-transform: uppercase;" hlp="JDCD" maxlength="5">
```

Can anyone please help

Comment: What Driver are you using? Also, have you verified (e.g. by manual inspection or automated screenshot) that the input actually has text at the moment you check it? The JavaDoc for `getText()` says "Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace." so it should work.

Comment: Andrew, the input text contains value. But looks like the value is not visible in html. Any idea on how to handle a situation like this?

Comment: You're definitely missing a `value` attribute, so unless this is added at runtime then I don't see where the value you expect will come from. Also your input tag is not closed.

Comment: Yeah i see that the input tag has not been closed. But I have pasted the html code as such.

Comment: Andrew, the value is present in the DOM.           input#WBJDCD.inforTextbox property value = "1" attribute value = "null"      How to retrieve the value present in the DOM?any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need `elem.getAttribute("value")`, which will return the current **value** (whether set via an HTML attribute, or a DOM property set via JavaScript etc.) Of course that could potentially be null too.

`getText()` returns the innerText of the element (i.e. `<input ...>Hello</input>` which is not what you want.

Comment: When i Execute the script via browser document.getElementById('WBJDCD').value. It return proper value. But when I run it via java - js.executeScript("document.getElementById('WBJDCD').value. It returns null  {document.getElementById(...) is null}

Comment: If you're running Java why not just use `getAttribute("value")` and solve your problem rather than executing JS? The reason your `executeScript()` is returning null is because there's no `return ...;` in your script, so the method has nothing to return.

Comment: Thanks a lot getAttribute("value") worked :) :) yaayyy